# Check for undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following function :

```
/**
       * ParkingTime Duration, which is shown by the size of each circle/bubble.
       *
       * @param garage
       * @param res
       * @returns {*}
       */
      function getParkingDuration(garage, res) {
        var parking = res.parking;
        var parking_duration = Array();
        for (var j = 0; j < parking.length; j++) {
          if (typeof parking[j][garage].parkingtime != 'undefined') {
            parking_duration.push(parking[j][garage].parkingtime);
          } else {
            parking_duration.push(0.1);
          }
        }

        return parking_duration;
      }
```

if there is an undefined variable, i want to push a value to some array.

But when i check my console i still see some errors of parkingtime undefined.

Why the code is not reaching my else statement?

Comment: what is the actual text of the error? Might it be saying that you cannot access parkingtime of undefined, which would mean `parking[j][garage]` is undefined

Comment: can you console.log(typeof parking[j][garage].parkingtime) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion:

```
  function getParkingDuration(garage, res) {
    var parking = res.parking || []; // in case res is undefined
    var parking_duration = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < parking.length; j++) {
      parking_duration[j]=0.1; // default
      if (parking[j] &&
          parking[j][garage] &&
          parking[j][garage].parkingtime) {               
        parking_duration[j]=parking[j][garage].parkingtime;
      }
    }
    return parking_duration;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all:

```
var parking = res.parking; //if res is undefined you'll get an error
```

second:

```
for (var j = 0; j < parking.length; j++) { //if parking is undefined you'll get an error
```

3)
if `parking[j][garage]` is undefined:

```
if (typeof parking[j][garage].parkingtime != 'undefined') { //will give error
```

That's more or less what you need:

```
function getParkingDuration(garage, res) {
        var parking_duration = Array();
        if(res && res.parking){
          var parking = res.parking;

          for (var j = 0; j < parking.length; j++) {
            if (garage && parking[j][garage] && typeof parking[j][garage].parkingtime != 'undefined') {
              parking_duration.push(parking[j][garage].parkingtime);
            } else {
              parking_duration.push(0.1);
          }
        }
      }

     return parking_duration;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your object structure is (I mean - whether you are not defining `parkingtime` or defining it as `null` or `empty`), you can try

```
if ( !isNaN(parking[j][garage].parkingtime) ) 
{
}
```

this should work if your `parkingtime` is supposed to be an `Number` always.

I am assuming that it always reaches inside `if` statement since you said

> But when i check my console i still see some errors of parkingtime
>   undefined.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `undefined` without any string literals. So give like these
`(parking[j][garage].parkingtime == undefined)`.

Comment: [typeof returns a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Answer (score 0):

It look like parking[j][garage] itself is undefined.
Can you try this:

```
 /**
           * ParkingTime Duration, which is shown by the size of each circle/bubble.
           *
           * @param garage
           * @param res
           * @returns {*}
           */
          function getParkingDuration(garage, res) {
            var parking = res.parking;
            var parking_duration = Array();
            for (var j = 0; j < parking.length; j++) {
              if (typeof parking[j] == 'undefined') {
                  parking[j] = {};
              }
              if (typeof parking[j][garage] == 'undefined') {
                 parking[j][garage] = {};
              }
              if (typeof parking[j][garage].parkingtime != 'undefined') {
                parking_duration.push(parking[j][garage].parkingtime);
              } else {
                parking_duration.push(0.1);
              }
            }

            return parking_duration;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things you can check quickly using `console.log` to see what is going on with your code

1. Check if `res.parking` is defined
2. Check if `parking[j]` is defined
3. Check if `parking[j][garage]` is defined
4. Check if `parking[j][garage]` has the attribute `parkingtime'

It will help you see what is defined and what isn't and help you to better address your problem.